# Dropdown menu using Foundation, JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm currently working on a Mega-Menu for a school project, and it has to be in dropdown-style. We're using Foundation and Laravel for the whole project.

I've been trying to find a way to have colomns in the mega-menu, kind of like [this website](https://www.protest.eu/shop/category/men/)

However, the following code is the only solution that kinda works like I would like it to. It has the four colomns that I want, but I can't trigger it via a hover. My JQuery doesn't work, and I can't find a way to select the dropdown menu by CSS/SASS.

So, I have two questions: Is there a better way to format this menu (In HTML), and how can I activate the Hover trigger to activate the menu?

Here's my HTML code (Shortened, because it's pretty long):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top large-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container top-bar hide-for-small-only">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <div class="row dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                    <ul class="large-3 m-menu dropdown-content">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Technologie Verte</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/1">Énergie Verte</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/2">Anti-Pollution</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/3">Implants</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/4">Santé</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/5">Technologie Biologique</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="large-3 m-menu dropdown dropdown-content">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Divertissement</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/6">Réalité Augmentée (AR)</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/7">Réalité Virtuelle (VR)</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/8">Jeux Vidéos</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/9">Holograms</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/10">Gadgets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="large-3 m-menu dropdown dropdown-content">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Utilitaires</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/11">Wearables</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/12">Audio</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/13">Impression 3D</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/14">Maison Intelligente</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/15">Applications</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="large-3 m-menu dropdown dropdown-content">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Futuristes</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/16">Spatial</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/17">Temporel</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/18">Armée</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/19">Transportation</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/projets/categories/20">Intelligence Artificielle (AI)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS that I have isn't working, so if some of you need it, it would be my pleasure to post it. 
Thanks in advance to everyone replying! I'll also try to post a picture of what it looks like, however I currently have some problems with Wampserver, so I'll post it as soon as I can

Comment: I think it's better to post your current code to https://jsfiddle.net/, so we can see your complete code. And also we can play around there

Comment: There are different types of many mega-menu links.Please review this link(i.e. https://bootsnipp.com/search?q=mega+menu).

Comment: Please use the `zurb-foundation` tags, `foundation` is something completely different.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd this is Foundation Sites not Bootstrap.

Comment: "We're using Foundation ..."

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Here's the link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqa9easd/4/) you recommended, though it's a bit rough since I don't know how to add Foundation to it

Comment: @DanielRuf Oops sorry about that, didn't know they were different

Also, If you would rather start from scratch and just find an altogether better solution feel free to do so